# Service Fabric Add additional files

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to add a file to service fabric project. However I get file not found exception when running it locally and when published. What is the proper way to include a file as "content" in service fabric Service?

trying to do this:

```
var pfx = File.ReadAllBytes("cert.pfx"); // Exception - not found
```

Comment: Is the `cert.pfx` file part of your .NET project?  If so, did you set the "Copy to Output Directory" to either "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer"?

Comment: yes. i've added it to the Service Fabric service project. Content/Copy always

Comment: @ShaneKim: I just threw together a [simple Azure Service Fabric sample](https://github.com/patrick-steele/AzureServiceFabric-AddFile) using the VS 2017 template, added a file, set the build action to Copy Always and I was able to access it just as you do.  Are you sure your file is added to the Service Project and not the Application Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'data package' feature for this. They are deployed as an independently versionable part of the application package.

More info [here](http://henidak.com/2015/07/blog/) and [here](https://matthew-mckinney.com/azure-service-fabric-data-packages/).